# Adding rows to a DataGrid with a Sub

Tags: vb.net, datagrid

I am new to vb.net

So what I'm trying to do is add rows to a datagrid. I have been able to accomplish this by adding the following:

```
Public Class X

 Public Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    InitializeComponent()
    Dim items As New List(Of reportLine)()
    listview1.ColumnWidth = New DataGridLength(240)
    items.Add(New reportLine() With {.Items = "Total Project Funding", .Amount = 42.0})
    items.Add(New reportLine() With {.Items = "Sammy Doe", .Amount = 7})
    items.Add(New reportLine() With {.Items = "Sammy Doe", .Amount = 7})
    items.Add(New reportLine() With {.Items = "Sammy Doe", .Amount = 7})
    items.Add(New reportLine() With {.Items = "Sammy Doe", .Amount = 99})
    datagrid1.ItemsSource = items
End Sub
Private Sub rptLine(ByRef rptItem As String, ByRef rptAmount As Double)
    Dim items As New List(Of reportLine)()
    items.Add(New reportLine() With {.Items = rptItem, .Amount = rptAmount})
    datagrid1.ItemsSource = items
End Sub

End Class

Public Class reportLine
  Public Property Items() As String

  Public Property Amount() As Integer

End Class
```

What I want to do is be able to add a line within the button click event like this

```
rptLine("Report Line", 450)
rptLine("Report Line", 450)
rptLine("Report Line", 450)
```

I realize the rptLine Sub is creating a new instance of the Itemsource each time I call it. I have tried a number of things to get this to work and get roadblocked with each one.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using?  Your object is called ListView1 but you talk about GridView, which I'm not seeing in my VS 2010.  Also, you say you've tried a number of things, but please share more specifics - sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why 
it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time 
to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, 
and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! 
Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: there is so much there that is at least questionable, it is hard to know where to start.  But I'll try: a) is this WinForms or WebForms?  b) Why a Datagrid vs a DataGridView?  c) Is it really a DataGrid or a ListView?  d) Why the `InitializeComponent` in a click event (see 'a')? e) Why all the array of Lists (containing more arrays?) f) does that even compile or run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using a ListView?

```
Private Sub rptLine(ByRef rptItem As String, ByRef rptAmount As Double)
    Dim listItem As ListViewItem = ListView1.Items.Add(rptItem)
    listItem.Subitems.Add(rptAmount)
End Sub
```

Are you using a DataGridView?

```
Private Sub rptLine(ByRef rptItem As String, ByRef rptAmount As Double)
    Dim row As DataGridViewRow = DataGridView1.Rows(DataGridView1.Rows.Add())
    With row
        .Cells(column1Name.Name).Value = rptItems
        .Cells(column2Name.Name).Value = rptAmount
    End With
End Sub
```

You could probably simplify these a little further but that should give you the basic idea.